# Integral of $y(x)$ when $y(t)$ is in the equation

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I'm supposed to find the limit of $y(x)$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$ if $y$ is given by:

> $$y(x)=7+\int_0^x 4\frac{(y(t))^{2}}{1+t^2}dt$$

What I don't get is the $y(t)$ inside the integral. If I just knew how to clear that hurdle the rest would be easy.

Answer (score 1):

This leads to a (separable) *differential equation*. Differentiate both sides:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=4\frac{y^2}{1+t^2} \\
y^{-2}\,dy=\frac{4\,dt}{1+t^2} $$
Then integrate both sides, $-y^{-1}=4\arctan(t)+C$, so 
$$y(t)=\frac{-1}{4\arctan(t)+C}$$
and $C$ can be obtained by the initial condition $y(0)=7$, namely $C=-1/7$.

Comment: I'd call the independent variable $x$ rather than $t$, since the derivative of the integral with respect to $x$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Yes, I was hesitating which one to choose. I have chosen so to erase formally only the integral sign. Anyway, you are right..

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ and you get a differential equation.